# Filtering a list in Java and put the results in a new arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist, filter

I want to filter an arraylist of CmisObjects and put the objects that are correct (correct with the filter) in another arraylist.

I have 6 fields that need to be checked which are 1 text input, 3 select boxes and 2 date inputs. So i want the objects that match the values in the fields in the new arraylist.

I checked other questions on Stackoverflow, some of them were similar but I want to know if someone has a clearer answer with maybe some example code.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT
Here is some code i have now, it only checks for 2 fields.

```
    String zoekterm = request.getParameter("zoekterm").toLowerCase();
    String zoektermselect = request.getParameter("zoektermselect");
    String startdatum = request.getParameter("startdatum");
    String einddatum = request.getParameter("einddatum");
    String status = request.getParameter("status");
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    ArrayList<CmisObject> alleDossiers = (ArrayList<CmisObject>) request.getSession().getAttribute("alledossiers");
    ArrayList<CmisObject> filterlist = new ArrayList<CmisObject>();
    for (CmisObject dossier : alleDossiers) {
        String dossiernaam = dossier.getName().toLowerCase();
        String dossierexternepartij = ((String) dossier.getPropertyValue("oc:bedrijfsnaam")).toLowerCase();;
        String dossierstatus = ((String) dossier.getPropertyValue("oc:contractstatus"));
        String dossiertype = ((String) dossier.getPropertyValue("oc:contracttype"));
        if (zoektermselect.equals("Alle")) {
            if (dossiernaam.contains(zoekterm) || dossierexternepartij.contains(zoekterm)) {
                filterlist.add(dossier);
            }
        }
        if (zoektermselect.equals("Dossiernaam")) {
            if (dossiernaam.contains(zoekterm)) {
                filterlist.add(dossier);
            }
        }
        if (zoektermselect.equals("Externe partij")) {
            if (dossierexternepartij.contains(zoekterm)) {
                filterlist.add(dossier);
            }
        }
    }
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><head></head><body>");
    int counter = 1;
    for (CmisObject dossier : filterlist) {
        out.println("<div id='noderef" + counter + "'>" + dossier.getId() + "</div>");
        out.println("<div id='dossiernaam" + counter + "'>" + dossier.getName() + "</div>");
        out.println("<div id='externepartij" + counter + "'>" + dossier.getPropertyValue("oc:bedrijfsnaam") + "</div>");
        out.println("<div id='contracttype" + counter + "'>" + dossier.getPropertyValue("oc:contracttype") + "</div>");
        counter++;
    }
    out.println("<div id='counter'>" + counter + "</div></body></html>");
```

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried

Comment: @TFischer Till now i've just thought of how it would work, because the only way i know is to code an "if" for every possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be somewhat straightforward if I know what you're asking. I'm guessing you want to add objects to an `ArrayList<CmisObjects>` if all 6 parameters match? If so, you want something like this (pseudocode):

```
ArrayList<CmisObject> toReturn = new ArrayList<CmisObject>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < yourArrayListOfCmisObjects.size(); i++){
    CmisObject obj = yourArrayListOfCmisObjects.get(i); 
    if(obj.getParam1() == param1 && obj.getParam2() == param2 && ... obj.getParam6() == param6){
       toReturn.add(obj); 
    }
}
```

and then you can manipulate toReturn from there. Hope this helps!

===

**EDIT**: You can consolidate a lot of those if statements, and to be very fair, you could probably break them up into `boolean` expressions.

```
boolean bool1 = (zoektermselect.equals("Alle") && (dossiernaam.contains(zoekterm) || dossierexternepartij.contains(zoekterm)); 
boolean bool2 = (zoektermselect.equals("Dossiernaam") && dossiernaam.contains(zoekterm);
boolean bool3 = zoektermselect.equals("Externe partij") && dossierexternepartij.contains(zoekterm);
if(bool1 || bool2 || bool3){ 
    filterlist.add(dossier);
}
```

Comment: Yes i know, but it also has to work if for example only 3 fields are filled

Comment: Yes that cleans up the code a bit. But for example, if the "zoekterm" field is not filled in, but the "status" select field is set to a value it still has to find the objects that match the "status" select field.